# How to override view/base file in magento 2 like as we can override frontend file in design folder

Tags: magento2, overrides, frontend, view, base

I want to override view/base
If we override view/frontend folder then we follow this pattern

```
app/design/frontend/
here we create registration.php file 
               theme.xml
               and other extension(like as : Magento_Theme)
```

Can we follow same pattern for base folder...?
anyone please confirm me

If we can do same for base(dir).
then Please show me file structure.

Comment: Which file you want to override, please share the vendor path here ?

Comment: I want to override "vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/base(dir)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add these files in this path design/frontend//Magento_Bundle/
here you can add file according to file dir
layout file add to layout (dir), template file add to template (dir)

it is working for me